# Convert the factors of a variable into the columns of the dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Concentration  Value
Low            0.21
Medium         0.85    
Low            0.10
Low            0.36
High           2.21
Medium         0.50
High           1.85
```

I would like to transform it into a dataframe where the column names are the factors of the variable:

```
Low      Medium    High
0.21     0.85      2.21
0.10     0.50      1.85
0.367
```

I've tried using pivot_wider, however, the values for each of the factors are stored as vectors.

```
Low           Medium         High
c(0.21,...)   c(0.87 ,...)   c(1.47 ,...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an id variable for rows by group:

```r
dat %>% 
  group_by(Concentration) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Concentration, values_from = Value)

     id   Low Medium  High
  <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  0.21   0.85  2.21
2     2  0.1    0.5   1.85
3     3  0.36  NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `unstack` from `base R`

```
mx <- max(table(df1$Concentration))
data.frame(lapply(unstack(df1, Value ~ Concentration), `length<-`, mx))
  High  Low Medium
1 2.21 0.21   0.85
2 1.85 0.10   0.50
3   NA 0.36     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Concentration = c("Low", "Medium", "Low", "Low", 
"High", "Medium", "High"), Value = c(0.21, 0.85, 0.1, 0.36, 2.21, 
0.5, 1.85)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```